# Field Pack List in a Channel Form

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack

Using a Field Pack List fieldtype in a channel form fails due to the need to hit enter to add a new line per list item.

How does one prevent the entire form from submitting when a user hits enter?

Comment: Open your developer console on your channel entry form. You getting JavaScript errors?

Comment: Yes:  Uncaught TypeError: $ul.sortable is not a function
But I can see the script being loaded from the fieldpack themes

Answer (score 0):

Had to add jQuery UI myself on the page as the EE version is outdated and doesn't include sortable.